# Android NFC: other RFID tags

Tags: android, nfc, rfid

I have been looking into nfc on the android platform, I have a few RFID tags laying around but they dont want to interact with the nexus s. i believe that the tags arent supported by the andriod nfc module (I can for example read my old card of college, which is mifare classic). for reference I have linked to a webstore selling these things.
Is it possible to use these tags with android? Will it be a lot of coding/hacks?

here is a link to the rfid tags:
http://www.parallax.com/StoreSearchResults/tabid/768/txtSearch/tag/List/0/SortField/4/ProductID/693/Default.aspx

any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tags you link to operate on 125kHz. NFC operates on 13.56MHz, so it is incompatible with your tags. There is now way a software hack can overcome this.

Comment: Was looking to see if my NFC would read my 125kHz prox card. Google search, found your answer. Thanks for the help.